# SAML Potentially Dangerous Request.Form Value

Tags: encoding, authentication, url, xml

I recently started using SAML for my website's authentication which is working great except 1 particular problem.

Some users (all of them are in the same domain group policy if that helps) get an error while loading the website :

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

I know this error doesn't occur because of the website's code since it always worked and still works fine on 95% of the users.

I've done some reading on SAML and it seems the SAML request is transmitted via the URL by encoding an XML-like message :

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

to get this base64-encoded message :

```
https://idp.example.org/SAML2/SSO/Redirect?SAMLRequest=fZFfa8IwFMXfBb9DyXvaJtZ1BqsURRC2
Mabbw95ivc5Am3TJrXPffmmLY3%2FA15Pzuyf33On8XJXBCaxTRmeEhTEJQBdmr%2FRbRp63K3pL5rPhYOpkVdY
ib%2FCon%2BC9AYfDQRB4WDvRvWWksVoY6ZQTWlbgBBZik9%2FfCR7GorYGTWFK8pu6DknnwKL%2FWEetlxmR8s
BHbHJDWZqOKGdsRJM0kfQAjCUJ43KX8s78ctnIz%2Blp5xpYa4dSo1fjOKGM03i8jSeCMzGevHa2%2FBK5MNo1F
dgN2JMqPLmHc0b6WTmiVbsGoTf5qv66Zq2t60x0wXZ2RKydiCJXh3CWVV1CWJgqanfl0%2Bin8xutxYOvZL18NK
UqPlvZR5el%2BVhYkAgZQdsA6fWVsZXE63W2itrTQ2cVaKV2CjSSqL1v9P%2FAXv4C
```

Now, If the XML-like message was encoded, there wouldn't be a problem transmitting a few characters over the URL. I suspect the problem is that the XML-like message is being sent without being encoded resulting in illegal characters ('<', '>') in the URL.

NOTE : The first time they open the website is successful, the error occurs only after the first time. If they clear the cookies they can open the website. (again, only once, then the error occurs until they clear the cookies again)

Does anyone has any idea what could be the cause of the message not be encoded for certain users/computers? or how can I know which URL is the SAML generating (so I can find out if the XML is really not being encoded)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the page address was :

```
https://ServerName.ServerDomain/AppName
```

and some users were using this address :

```
https://ServerName/AppName
```